# Multiply validators in Spring Boot context

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to use two types of validation in my Spring Boot application.

Validation point is:

```
@PostMapping("/api/register")
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void add(@Valid @RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
    log.debug("User registration request: " + userDto.getEmail());
}
```

UserDto:

```
public class UserDto {
@NotEmpty
@Email
private String email;
@NotEmpty
@Password
private String password;
@NotEmpty
private String confirmPassword;
@NotEmpty
@Phone
private String phoneNumber;
...
```

It works.

And than I added one more custom validator to check password matching and declare it as Bean:

```
@Component
public class PasswordMatchesValidator implements Validator {

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
    return UserDto.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
    UserDto userDto = (UserDto) o;

    if (Objects.isNull(userDto.getPassword()))
        return;

    if (!userDto.getPassword().equals(userDto.getConfirmPassword()))
        errors.rejectValue("confirmPassword", "Passwords don't match.", "Passwords don't match.");
}}
```

**In non Spring Boot test context works following solution**:

```
@Autowired
private PasswordMatchesValidator validator;

@InitBinder
private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addValidators(validator);
}
```

But in Spring Boot application Spring replaces all validators for UserDto with my `PasswordMatchesValidator` bean and **other validators don't works!**

Now, I had removed `@Component` annotation from `PasswordMatchesValidator`
changed controller code to:

```
private PasswordMatchesValidator validator =
    new PasswordMatchesValidator();

@InitBinder
private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addValidators(validator);
}
```

and it is works. But I'm sure that it is possible to use `@Component` and `@Autowired` annotations to wire my beans like in test context.

How I can configure Spring to solve this misunderstanding?

Help me please to make my code a bit cleaner. :)

Thanks!

Comment: What configuration classes are you using in your Spring Boot app? I suggest manually registering a standard validatior bean: override `getValidator()` in your `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` with `new OptionalValidatorFactoryBean();`

Comment: If it's possible, I suggest to rewrite validation to use beanvalidators (JSR303 & Co).